# Add index with SQL Server XML Import

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xml-parsing

In SQL Server, I try to use the XML functions to import a file as follows:

```
SELECT 
    file.value('@registrationnumber[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS [registrationnumber],
    report.value('@nihil[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS [nihil],
    report.value('@period[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS [period],
    report.value('@formulaid[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS [formulaid],
    report.value('@frequention[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS [frequention],
    report.value('@versieon[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS [version],
    variant.value('@type[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS [varianttype],
    variant.value('@value[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS [variantvalue],
    post.value('@cube[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS [cube],
    post.value('@row[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS [row],
    post.value('@rownr[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS [rownr],
INTO
    [#parsed]
FROM
    @xmlData.nodes('file') AS a(file)
CROSS APPLY
    file.nodes('report') AS b(report)
CROSS APPLY
    report.nodes ('post') AS c(post)
OUTER APPLY
    report.nodes ('variant') AS d(variant)
```

I was wondering if it would be possible to automatically add an additional column with the unique index for **each report** that is loaded in.

I was unable to find the solution on google, because I think I am using wrong search terms.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ROW_NUMBER()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
SELECT 
    file.value('@registrationnumber[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS [registrationnumber],
    report.value('@nihil[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS [nihil],
    report.value('@period[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS [period],
    report.value('@formulaid[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS [formulaid],
    report.value('@frequention[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS [frequention],
    report.value('@versieon[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS [version],
    variant.value('@type[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS [varianttype],
    variant.value('@value[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS [variantvalue],
    post.value('@cube[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS [cube],
    post.value('@row[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS [row],
    post.value('@rownr[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS [rownr],
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) YourSequentialIndex
INTO
    [#parsed]
FROM
    @xmlData.nodes('file') AS a(file)
        CROSS APPLY
    file.nodes('report') AS b(report)
        CROSS APPLY
    report.nodes ('post') AS c(post)
        OUTER APPLY
    report.nodes ('variant') AS d(variant)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I was unclear in my question, but I wanted to index each <report></report> in my XML and not every row in the SQL table. With your solution, I was able to solve the problem:

DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY report)